# I've stored form names in a data base. now i want to load forms by using those names

Tags: c#

I've stored form names in a data base. Now I want to load forms by using those names.
Here is my table structure:

```
frmID, Item_Name, formName
```

Here is my code:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        //TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        string item = Convert.ToString(treeView1.SelectedNode);

        int index = item.IndexOf(" ");
        if (index > 0)
            item = item.Substring(index + 1); 
        //MessageBox.Show(item);
        var selectedFRM = from Menu in dbdata.Menus
                          where Menu.Item_Name == item
                          select Menu;
        foreach (var pick in selectedFRM.Take(1))
        {
            string sel = pick.Form_Name;
            Assembly asm = typeof(Form).Assembly;
            Type type = asm.GetType(sel);

            string df = Convert.ToString(type);
            MessageBox.Show(df);
            AssemblyName assemName = asm.GetName();
            MessageBox.Show(assemName.Name);
            try
            {
            Form frmChk = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);                
                frmChk.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in loading form");
            }
           // MessageBox.Show(sel);
        }
```

upto `Assembly asm = typeof(Form).Assembly;` code is working properly. How can I load a form by using the "formName" which is in the database

Comment: You need to reformat your question so its easier to read.

Comment: You also need to ask an actual question. You've said how far it's working, but not what happens when it *doesn't* work...

Answer (score 5):

This is the problem, I suspect:

```
Assembly asm = typeof(Form).Assembly;
Type type = asm.GetType(sel);
```

That assembly will be the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly - which obviously doesn't include *your* specific forms. Just use *any* of the forms you know is in the right assembly, instead of `Form`:

```
// Or whatever you know about, of course...
Assembly asm = typeof(LoginForm).Assembly;
```

Note that the name will still need to be the namespace-qualified name.

Another (more flexible) alternative is to store the *assembly-qualified* name of the type which you can obtain via [`Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx). Then you can just use `Type.GetType(aqName)` - which means your code will still work if you split your forms across multiple assemblies.

Comment: then how can I load that foarm

Comment: without "Type type = asm.GetType(sel);" how can I create instace of the form and load it?

Comment: @user1508417: It's not clear what you mean. Either you still use `asm.GetType(...)` if you can get at the right assembly with a well-known type, or you use `Type.GetType()` instead of `Assembly.GetType`.

Comment: Actually what I want is load a specific form by using the database. in this code I can't do that. so how can I do that? the table field is formName.

Comment: @user1508417: **Why** can't you load a specific form? It's really unclear where you're stuck. I've given you two different ways of getting to the relevant type.

Comment: @user1508417: Well what about it? `LoginForm` is just a dummy example - use *any* type that you know will be in the right assembly. It's very hard to help you when you're providing so little information - please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Jon Skeet: Sir in this  Assembly asm = typeof(formName).Assembly; line, the formName is changing time to time. And I fetch from the database by using string formName = pick.Form_Name; so it generates some error. Actually I am new to this language and still learning. if you can please put some sample code.

Comment: the only problem I had the abow code is in line "Type type = asm.GetType(sel);" value of the type variable is always null.

Comment: @user1508417s: Well it won't be if you give it the namespace-qualified type name, asking in the right assembly. Unfortunately it's hard to say what you're doing wrong without any more information - like the name you're getting from the database. My guess is that the problem is that you've just got the "simple" type name, without the namespace, but you need to give us more information. Your *code* is fine, assuming you've got an appropriate assembly reference. (You *still* haven't told us whether all the types will be in one assembly, so it's okay to obtain an assembly reference this way.)

Comment: I have created some forms like frmCustomer, frmEmployee, etc. and I created amenu with a treewiew. In treeview menu is like Customer, Employee, etc. data table has id, item_name, form_Name which contains ID, name in the treeview, form name. once click on item the relevent form should be loaded. (data table id - int, item_name - vachar(50), form_Name - vachar(50))

Comment: @user1508417: You *still* haven't given any examples of the actual value of the field. As I've said before, I strongly suspect that your values don't include the namespace. I'm sorry, but if you're not going to provide the information I've asked for, I'm not going to be able to help you any further. I've given everything you should need to get this working: you use `typeof(...).Assembly` to get the assembly, then `Assembly.GetType` with a *namespace-qualified* type name to get to the `Type`, then `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance.

Comment: (I'd also *strongly* encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions, and make your type names more descriptive - e.g. `DisplayEmployeeForm`.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. the `Type type = asm.GetType(sel);` line should corrected like this.

```
Type type = asm.GetType("WindowsFormsApplication6." + sel);
```

That means

```
Type type = asm.GetType("Namespace.Class");
```